# Javascript: Get index of first special regex character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, path, wildcard, glob

Given a user-inputted string with unknown regexes, I want to get the index of the first special regex character. (For my use case, the string will be a path.)

Examples:

`foo/*/bar` -> 4

`foo?/*/*/` -> 3

`foofoo+?/**/` -> 6

Comment: FWIW: Those probably aren't the desired path expressions. Usually such is done with 'glob expressions' and not actual regular expressions. Basic path globs would only consider `*` (and`**`) and `?` as special constructs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of what is below.  Just update the function to include each character you're wanting to find the index of.  Below should match what you gave as examples and return the proper values.

```
var match = /[*?+^${}[\]().|\\]/.exec("foo/*bar");
if (match) {
    console.log(match.index);
}
```

Comment: Updated the solution to escape all of the characters I could think of that might cause issues with the regex. May be a better way of escaping them, but this is tested and works.

Comment: You do realize that characters in a character class (`[abc]`) don't need to be escaped, right? And don't need to be separated by pipes? Also, you're expression will return a lot of false positives: `a < b`, `a & b`, and so on will all return a match, while they don't contain characters with special meaning.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen true, thank you for the heads up. I'm not the greatest at reg expressions and can see your points. I've always escaped them for piece of mind and the way I wrote it made sense with the pipes. Will update for easier readability and false positives. Thanks!

Comment: I removed the downvote. It looks correct now (well, it's basically the same as the one in my answer).

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I just removed all the slashes and pipes from my original. Plus updated to remove false positives. Thanks for pointing out the issues :)

Answer (score 0):

To include all characters with special meaning in a regular expression, it would probably end up looking something like this:

```
var re = /[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/;
var match = re.exec('foo/*/bar');

if (match) {
    console.log(match.index);
}
```

The expression itself is borrowed from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)'s documentation on how to escape literal string input to be used in a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

## `.search`

This is what `.search` was made for:

```
var index = "Foo/*/bar".search(/[*?+^${}[\]().|\\]/);
```

## RegEx

You can use the `.index` property of a RegExp function:

```
var index = ("Foo/*/bar".match(/[*?+^${}[\]().|\\]/) || {}).index
```

Comment: Your bottom example will generate an *Uncaught TypeError* for strings that don't contain a special character. Also, there's no `index` property on a `RegExp` object. There is one on the result of a `match` operation though.

Comment: To be clear: I didn't get upset, and I pointed out more than a simple grammar mistake. Your bottom example contained a logical error, and pointing that out in a comment seems like a reasonable thing to do. My comment was matter-of-factly, objective, and I didn't call you names as you seem prone to do. Your profile says that if you downvote, you will leave a comment, and that if you get downvoted you want an explanation and will try to fix. Well, I provided an explanation for my downvote. Your revenge-downvote on one of my questions did not go unnoticed, but I didn't find your comment.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was find the index of the first special character if a string has:

```
var str = "fo@ao/*bar";
var match = /[^A-Za-z 0-9]/g.exec(str)
if(match){
    console.log(match.index);
}
```